# Can't compile file using Compass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have tried both ways to compile a project using compass (i.e. via the gui app, and the command line.)
I get this error in both instances. "Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help." 
Where do you add the directory argument?

Comment: Can someone please help!

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am using the "Compass gui app" But I can do the terminal too!

Comment: Can someone please HELP!

Comment: Hm, I don't have any experience wit Compass.app. However, I've been extremely happy with [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/). Its super easy to use and has a feature that will set up a Compass project for you, which I've used numerous times with no issues. Its got a free trial, too, so why not give it a shot?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the path to your compass project, what commands you tried on command line and where your config.rb is located(and whats in it). I think you simply have wrong paths.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the way to get this working is just switch to your directory for your project and then run

```
compass init
```

This will then create you a "working" config.rb, and a directory called sass, and a directory stylesheets
and a couple of start scss files.
If you do not want them, or want to use different directories, you can of course now edit your freshly created and working config.rb, and change your directories (and then delete the old automatically created ones)

Anyway having done that(or not) you should then be able to run

```
compass watch
```

and all should be good , i.e. your scss files get compiled to css files
Or then run your gui tool

More information to be found in the compass documentation [here](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/command-line/)